# How do I simplify this expression involving the exponential function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ \frac{e^{16}-e^{-16}}{e^8-e^{-8}}$

How do I simplify this expression involving e to $\frac {1+e^{16}}{e^8}$?

I have tried multiplication and division by e^8 and e^16 and simplifying the denominator and numerator separately but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{e^{16} - e^{-16}}{e^8 - e^{-8}} = \frac{\left(e^8 - e^{-8}\right)\left(e^8 + e^{-8}\right)}{e^8 - e^{-8}} = e^8 + e^{-8} = e^8 + \frac{1}{e^8} = \frac{e^{16} + 1}{e^8} = \frac{1 + e^{16}}{e^8}$$

Answer (score 6):

Hint:$$\frac{u^2-v^2}{u-v}=u+v$$